# C++ Vector troubles

Tags: c++, search, vector

Heres a function of my program, which keeps crashing. The purpose of the function is the search through the vectors and display what they rank and the frequency, which is read into thier respective vectors. Im guessing its my while loop but im not sure.
The vectors are correctly read in.

```
void searchNames(vector<string> girlsname,vector<int> girlsfeq,vector<string> boysname,vector<int> boysfeq){
    string name1;
    string name;
    int SIZE = girlsname.size();
    int SIZE2 = boysname.size();
    while(name1 != "quit"){
        int i=0;
        int frank=find(girlsname.begin(), girlsname.end(), name1) - girlsname.begin();
        int mrank=find(boysname.begin(), boysname.end(), name1) - boysname.begin();
        name1.clear();
        name.clear();
        cout << "Please enter a name: ";
        cin >> name1;
        cout << endl;
        while(i< SIZE && name1 !=girlsname[i++]){

       frank++;

        }
        name.clear();
        i=0;
        while(i< SIZE2 && name1 !=boysname[i++]){

        mrank++;

        }
        cout << left << setw(15) << "Name" << right << setw(10) << "Girl Rank" << right << setw(10) << "Frequency" << right << setw(10) << "Boy Rank"<< right << setw(10) << "Frequency" << endl;
        if(frank != SIZE && mrank != SIZE2){
        cout << left << setw(15) << name1 << right << setw(10) << frank << right << setw(10) << girlsfeq[frank] << right << setw(10) << mrank << right << setw(10) << boysfeq[mrank] << endl;
} 

}
```

Comment: You need to set `i` back to `0` before the second `while` loop.

Comment: A [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful, otherwise we have to guess a lot.

Comment: What line is it crashing on? What does the crash message say? What did you discover when you ran it under a debugger?

Comment: Barmar just tried reseting i=0; after the first while doesnt fix, dont know which line.

Comment: printing the result would access element out-of-bound if no match is found for the entered name. So, unless user enters a name that is both in the girl vector _and_ the boy vector, the last `cout` line will result in undefined behavior (likely a crash).

Comment: If I thought that would solve the problem I would have posted it as an answer. P.S. Remember to put `@` before usernames if you want to reply to them.

Comment: Thanks let me try that. One sec

Comment: Have you considered trying to debug the program? Like, with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

First, in any of your loops, you don't change the value of `i`, so they are potentially infinite.

Second, if I understand what you're trying to do, you have paired vectors and you search for an index on which the name is in the first vector and then use it to get the value from second vector. You can use `std::find` function for that:

```
int frank = find(girlsname.begin(), girlsname.end(), name1) - girlsname.begin();
```

Now, you can access the `girlsfreq[frank]` value. If the name is not present in the vector, the `frank` equals size of the vector, which you have to check for. Don't forget to add include:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: How exactly and where? Can you post the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your crash. Instead, I am able to reproduce an infinite loop. Taking a closer look to your `while` loops, it becomes evident: the value of i is never changing. If it cannot find a name match, it will keep incrementing the value of `frank`. So, a fix to this problem would be:

```
    while(i < SIZE && name1 != name) {
        name = girlsname[i];
        frank++;
        i++;
    }
```

But it can be improved: you don't need that assignment. Also, you can use the advantage of the postfix increment:

```
    while(i < SIZE && name1 != girlsname[i++]){
        frank++;
    }
```

Doing this, you also remove the necessity of `name` and `name1`.